# Add a custom input from phtml in admin form

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, phtml, adminform

I'm using custom phtml to display some data in an admin Ui form tab, and I want to be able to have a custom input that would get sent to the controller when I hit 'save'

ui_form.xml

```
 <fieldset name="comments">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Comments</item>
            <item name="collapsible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
            <item name="canShow" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <container name="custom_tab_container">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="string">1</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <htmlContent name="html_content">
            <argument name="block" xsi:type="object">Path/To/My/Block/Rendering/Data</argument>
        </htmlContent>
    </container>

</fieldset>
```

What I want:

custom_template.phtml

```
<?php

/** @var $block Path/To/My/Block/Rendering/Data */
?>

<div id="custom_input_id">
    <input name="custom_input" value="default" />
</div>
```

Current result:
[image]
Right now everything renders like it should, except that the data from my custom input is not sent to the save controller. How can I make this work ?

Answer (score 0):

Found out, I just needed to add a `data-form-part="<name_of_ui_form_file>"` to my input like so :

```
<input name="custom_input" value="default" data-form-part="custom_ui_form"/>
```